# How to scroll down to bottom using selenium in ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, scroll, selenium-webdriver

Can you show me the way to use `selenium` in ruby to scroll down to bottom of page? I read this

```
element = driver.find_element(:xpath, "//div[@class='footer small']")
element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

but in this [link](http://www.mobileswall.com/), i can't find any element. Can you show me the way without element like that found. Thank you!

Comment: Good idea would be to give the HTML document..

Comment: @ArupRakshit i edited my question with the link, can you help me? thank you!

Comment: page is being loaded dynamically.

Comment: @ArupRakshit: But as I see, To continue load it, we must scroll down

Comment: have you tried using `find_element(:css, "#mm-blocker")` seems like the last element on the page to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When I looked at the page, I did not see a div with class footer. This might be why you cannot find the element.

For me, the last visible element appears to be the wallpapers - ie div with class pic. You can get the last picture and scroll to it using the following. Note that we find all of the pictures and then take the last one in the collection.

```
last_picture = driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.pic').last
last_picture.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

After you scroll to the last wallpaper, you will want to wait for the page to finish loading. For example, the following will wait until the image count increases:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.navigate.to 'http://www.mobileswall.com/'

# Check how many elements are there initially  
puts driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.pic').length
#=> 30

# Scroll to the last image
driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.pic').last.location_once_scrolled_into_view

# Wait for the additional images to load
current_count = driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.pic').length
until current_count < driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.pic').length
  sleep(1)
end

# Check how many elements are there now
puts driver.find_elements(:css, 'div.pic').length
#=> 59
```